# Performing Matched sampling in R for three treatment group samples from observational data

Tags: r, sampling

I would like to use propensity score matching or some other type of matched sampling method to match three samples. Essentially I have an overall population and I would like to draw three random samples from the population  which differ by a characteristic, say treatment type. Assuming I sample these three groups call them treatment group A,B, and C I then want to perform propensity score matching across the  three groups. The MatchIT package in R only allows binary treatments does anyone know of another package and function which allows multiple treatments?  Thanks

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405019/matching-with-multiple-treatments/405063#405063). Don't limit yourself to `twang`.

Answer (score 0):

The twang package in R solves my problem.